# ggplot2 seemingly places distinct points at the same x position?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, facet

I'm having trouble with a ggplot2 plot.  I'm trying to display a set of points where the x axis is year and y axis is a floating point.  There are two facets, 'type' and 'group' which has 4 and 2 values respectively.  Strangely, year values which are distinct seem to be placed at the same year position in the plots.  I assume I'm doing something wrong, but not sure what.

[image: Plot]

```
library(ggplot2)

csv <- '"","year","type","meanPM2.5","group"
"1","1999","NON-ROAD",0.650193156943192,"Baltimore"
"2","1999","NONPOINT",53.8128535945545,"Baltimore"
"3","1999","ON-ROAD",0.384811951879435,"Baltimore"
"4","1999","POINT",23.7744225574713,"Baltimore"
"5","2002","NON-ROAD",0.556466983374061,"Baltimore"
"6","2002","NONPOINT",33.4348242946658,"Baltimore"
"7","2002","ON-ROAD",0.173168130596644,"Baltimore"
"8","2002","POINT",14.131129233003,"Baltimore"
"9","2005","NON-ROAD",0.512356196792363,"Baltimore"
"10","2005","NONPOINT",31.8169245427152,"Baltimore"
"11","2005","ON-ROAD",0.148555691013436,"Baltimore"
"12","2005","POINT",13.6351701910803,"Baltimore"
"13","2008","NON-ROAD",0.295555123686582,"Baltimore"
"14","2008","NONPOINT",20.8642755980118,"Baltimore"
"15","2008","ON-ROAD",0.117856744706526,"Baltimore"
"16","2008","POINT",2.24419944428104,"Baltimore"
"17","1999","NON-ROAD",5.81044444444444,"Total"
"18","1999","NONPOINT",84.305,"Total"
"19","1999","ON-ROAD",1.80635416666667,"Total"
"20","1999","POINT",22.8303846153846,"Total"
"21","2002","NON-ROAD",2.16979209254948,"Total"
"22","2002","NONPOINT",41.9305555555556,"Total"
"23","2002","ON-ROAD",0.418407542677101,"Total"
"24","2002","POINT",8.49641791044776,"Total"
"25","2005","NON-ROAD",2.2426458532036,"Total"
"26","2005","NONPOINT",41.9305555555556,"Total"
"27","2005","ON-ROAD",0.402562900882384,"Total"
"28","2005","POINT",16.9364788732394,"Total"
"29","2008","NON-ROAD",0.536765014018269,"Total"
"30","2008","NONPOINT",30.5157179549356,"Total"
"31","2008","ON-ROAD",0.313033536852635,"Total"
"32","2008","POINT",1.28722083560821,"Total"'

w <- read.csv(text = csv)
qplot(w$year, w$meanPM2.5, data=w, facets = type~group)
```

Comment: Temporary solution using other notation `ggplot(w,aes(x = year, y = meanPM2.5)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(type~group)`

Comment: Definitely try to stay away from `qplot`. I'm nearly finished with a Hadley-inspired initiative to rid the `ggplot` docs of `qplot` everywhere but the actual `qplot` function example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to specify w for your axis as its qplot already knows this from the data parameter. See below, it gives me the outcome that I would expect.

`qplot(year, meanPM2.5, data=w, facets = type~group`)

Comment: That does give me the correct output but I don't understand why.  Can you explain why this makes a difference?

Comment: I'll take a stab at it. If we look at what is going on behind the scenes with 'qplot' we see that it makes some assumptions and then eventually calls 'ggplot' in the 'parent.frame()' 'env'.  Looking at 'ggplot' we see that the object 'p' is what actually is holding our ggplot object and that there is no indpendent x or y. It is called within a list from 'p$data'. So pretty much when you say 'w$year' your not calling a unique object but rather that subset of w(which is why it works nicely when w is assumed but not provided). In a nutshell qplot is looking at 'w$year' as it relates to w.